# Непонятная семантика addEventListener в вызове внешнего обработчика.

Tags: события, javascript

Первый из приведенных примеров отлично работает и отлавливает событие на нужном элементе, в то время, как второй сообщает о том, что e == unefined и никакого свойства .target у него не может быть.

**1:**

```
table.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
var target = event.target;

while(target.tagName !== 'TD') {
    target = target.parentNode;
    if (target === list) return;
}

alert(target.id);

});
```

**2:**

```
 table.addEventListener('click', callbackFun(event));
    function callbackFun(e) {
        var target = e.target;

        while(target.tagName !== 'TD') {
            target = target.parentNode;
            if (target === table) return;
        }

        alert(target.id);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Это потому-что во втором случае вы делаете вторым аргументом не функцию а ее результат.

исправьте на

```
table.addEventListener('click', callbackFun);
function callbackFun(e) {
    var target = e.target;

    while(target.tagName !== 'TD') {
        target = target.parentNode;
        if (target === table) return;
    }

    alert(target.id);

}
```

Comment: спасибо, уже разобрался самостоятельно. Как раз хотел откомментировать.